# Android-how to delete specific message from sent item or don't show sent message when using following code..?

Tags: android, android-intent, smsmanager

this is my sample code for sending message i want to use not show this message in sent item.

```
    String strPhone = "XXXXXXXXXXX";

String strMessage = "Lorem\nIpsum";

SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

sms.sendTextMessage(strPhone, null, strMessage, null, null);

Toast.makeText(this, "Sent.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

i want to delete this sended message from sent items or now show in sent item.
in all version.
please help me to solve out.

Comment: You can do this only in JellyBin and below versions.

Answer (score 0):

Query your conversations after sending the message. Then fetch that particular message by comparing the message contents using any unique keyword in your sent message.I have tried this code in my phone running Marshmallow.

```
    Uri uriSMS = Uri.parse("content://sms/conversations");
    Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMS, null, null, null, null);
    if(cur != null && cur.moveToNext()) {
       do {
            String smsContent = cur.getString(2);
            if(smsContent.contains("your sms keyword")) {
                String pid = cur.getString(0); // Get id;
                String uri = "content://sms/" + pid;
                getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse(uri), null, null);
            }
       } while (cur.moveToNext());
    }
```

Comment: **-@Febi Mathew**   error occur for permission access...            `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.telephony.SmsProvider uri content://sms/61 from pid=30990, uid=10186 requires android.permission.WRITE_SMS, or grantUriPermission()`

Comment: Include WRITE_SMS and READ_SMS permission in Manifest.

Comment: also try this.. but not delete

Comment: `private void deleteMessage(){
Uri uriSMS = Uri.parse("content://sms/conversations");
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMS, null, null, null, null);
 if(cur != null && cur.moveToNext()) {
           do {
                String smsContent = cur.getString(2);
                if(smsContent.contains("Demo")) {
                    String pid = cur.getString(0); // Get id;
                    String uri = "content://sms/" + pid;
                    getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse(uri), null, null);
                }
            } while (cur.moveToNext());
        }
   }`

Comment: Try debugging your code and see whether it reads all conversations in your phone. Also check logcat and see any error is there

Comment: no any error occur and i already debug when my message contain "Demo" keyword this will enter in if() and perfom all operation but i'll check in message my message not deleted.

Comment: **@Febi Mathew**  am using 4.4.2 kitkat it's work on it..?